# Printing DataGridView using built in functions? c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, printing

I have had a root aroud the internet, and cant seem to find anything. I just want to print my datagridview from a UI. I can't use any external DLL's as I'm at work, and I was wondering how to do this without the downloading of anything. I'm banging my head against a brick wall! I don't know how to create an object to print, or how to print the object. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to paint the Dgv or maybe the data inside it?

Comment: Either really, it doesn't matter to me. I just require the data on a peice of paper from a button click.

Comment: you are working on a windows form application?

Comment: Yes I am, its an address book, and I require to print the records that are within the data grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

[How To Print a Data Grid in C# and .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET11212005060838AM/HowToPrintaDataGridinCsHARPand.NET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is the following:

1. either expoert the results to excel and then printing the excel
2. replace the datagridview with report viewer which has the options of printing as excel or pdf.